# iOS 4 Unable to access variable crashes app

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios4, viewdidload

Under iOS 4, when my app installs from xcode it crashes on the first launch but not on subsiquent launches.

After commenting out some addSubView methods the debugger is finally giving me one piece of info

It crashes on [super viewDidLoad]. The debugger states:

> Unable to access variable "button1"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Breakpoint info from the console:

```
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""RootViewController.m":20" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - ""RootViewController.m":127" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - ""RootViewController.m":134" resolved
Pending breakpoint 4 - ""RootViewController.m":140" resolved
Pending breakpoint 5 - ""RootViewController.m":146" resolved
Pending breakpoint 6 - ""RootViewController.m":162" resolved
Pending breakpoint 7 - ""RootViewController.m":157" resolved
Pending breakpoint 8 - ""RootViewController.m":152" resolved
Pending breakpoint 9 - ""RootViewController.m":23" resolved
Pending breakpoint 10 - ""RootViewController.m":26" resolved
Pending breakpoint 11 - ""RootViewController.m":28" resolved
Pending breakpoint 12 - ""RootViewController.m":27" resolved
Pending breakpoint 13 - ""RootViewController.m":29" resolved
Pending breakpoint 14 - ""RootViewController.m":31" resolved
Pending breakpoint 15 - ""RootViewController.m":30" resolved
Pending breakpoint 16 - ""RootViewController.m":32" resolved
Pending breakpoint 17 - ""RootViewController.m":33" resolved
Pending breakpoint 18 - ""RootViewController.m":34" resolved
Pending breakpoint 19 - ""RootViewController.m":35" resolved
Pending breakpoint 20 - ""RootViewController.m":36" resolved
Pending breakpoint 21 - ""RootViewController.m":37" resolved
Pending breakpoint 22 - ""RootViewController.m":21" resolved
Pending breakpoint 23 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
```

Comment: Make sure you are building the "Debug" config. A "Release" config can producde the "Unable to access" message.

Comment: @James: How can "Release" config do that?  @yesimarobot: please provide more information, there's nothing wrong with the code fragment you have shown.  Please provide the exact exception message that occurs when it crashes and on what line?

Comment: "Release" enables optimizations that will occasionally result in the debugger not being able to "see" a variable.

Comment: The console is not showing any exception. the app stops at breakpoint 1 (the break point at [super viewDidload]) and the console just says 
(gdb)

Comment: I added the breakpoint info from the console to the main quesiton above.

Comment: When I run it with breakpoints off it doesn't crash. WTF.

Comment: The debugger stops at all breakpoints you set.  If you don't want it to stop there, remove or disable that breakpoint (or press the continue button to keep going).  Stopping at a breakpoint is not a crash.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message 'Unable to access variable' when trying to inspect a variable in debug mode.

As mentioned in one of the comments, my issue was that I was debugging my release build rather than the debug build.